# msbuild with code progress in various environments

Tags: msbuild, continuous-integration

I come from a Continuous Integration and Continuous Delivery (CI-CD) implementation project background for java web applications. Now i am working for a .NET based project. Microsoft technologies is completely new to me. It is using the MsBuild for the build process via Jenkins. I am learning MsBuild at this time. The more i read, the more confused i am with the Microsoft way of doing this.

I noticed that the msbuild is executed for every environment where the app is going to be deployed using various configuration and profiles based on the environment for the deployment. Below are some msbuild commands for 2 different environments (PIE & TEST)

```
C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MSBuild\\12.0\\Bin\\MSBuild.exe"  /p:Configuration=PIE /m:4 /nr:false src/myapp.sln

C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MSBuild\\12.0\\Bin\\MSBuild.exe"  /p:Configuration=TEST /t:Rebuild /m:2 /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=TEST src/myapp.sln

C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MSBuild\\12.0\\Bin\\MSBuild.exe" /p:Configuration=STAGE /t:Rebuild /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=STAGE /m:2 SprintA/src/myapp.sln
```

i may be wrong, but i feel that the code being deployed to the two environments (when the code progress from PIE to TEST) is being build for each environment which is not the real code progression concept. IMHO, the build is done once and its progressed to subsequent environments for testing/validation as long as there are no bugs in the code. The various environment specific settings are handled via config files inside the package and the containers (tomcat for a java app) are started with the parameters that reads/parse the confif files.

Is there a way to handle this in .NET? The app is deployed in IIS

UPDATE: 
The more i do research reading various docs and blogs, i came across the web publishing method using `msbuild` for each configuration and the deploy/publish profiles.  IS this just the standard way that the mass follows for a .net project's CICD?

Comment: Yeah, this is a bit of an anti pattern. You can do it this way, and if you use the abomination that is MSDeploy then it pushes you down that route. Your way of having a single build that progresses is much better. You need to decouple the build bit and the deploy bit.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is something Microsoft realized and is enforced using the new [Release System](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/release/manage-your-release-vs).

Basically you have a "process" (Build) building your code and producing artifacts (ie. website file structure, nuget package, installers, etc) in this process you typically take care of things like applying the version value to your assemblies, minifiying js and css files or anything not related with the any specific environment.

Then you have another "process" (Release) to configure your artifacts based on the environment where they will be deployed (ie. modifying web.config files from your website) and deploy those artifacts to the desired environment without having to build them again. (ie. push nuget package to some pre-production nuget feed, copy you website structure to the server, etc)

How do you implement these two "processes"?. Well, that depends on your preference and tools. If you use Visual Studio Team Services you have these processes clearly defined out of the box by the infrastructure, and a lot of built in task to support them.

I have not worked with Jenkins but as long as you can use msbuild you could have 2 msbuild projects one to build your artifacts from the source code on different branches and another one to deploy to different environments base on some configurations (ei. your PIE & TEST) and of course you could use tools like powershell or MSbuild custom tasks to support more advanced scenarios within your processes.

Comment: Looks like MS Release Management is a completely new animal now?  And not something that can be integrated via Jenkins like in the case of Maven Release management. If this is true, it would require moving some mountains to convince the folks for change. Do you have any gist, that i can refer on using MSbuild to deploy to various environments without involving a build, i.e using the pre-build artifacts?